# Imagick colorizeImage Hex darker

Tags: php, imagick

I use PHP and Imagick to change the color of a transparent PNG. The image in the PNG is a simple shape with a transparent background.

I use the colorizeImage function to change the color.

```
$img = new Imagick("shape.png");
$img->colorizeImage("#99ccff",0.0);
```

The problem is that Imagick show a dark version of my HEX code (`#99ccff`)?

Is there a way to get the exact color (`#99ccff`)?

(my PNG is PNG 32 - and the shape is black)

[image: http://www.2shared.com/photo/N3rGdoHG/shape3.html]

Comment: How are you comparing the colors? If you're doing something like looking at the color in Photoshop vs a browser you may see discrepancies.

Answer (score 5):

I thought I would answer this question despite that it is old. This is for anyone else having this problem.

I solved this for a project I am working on by simply using "Clut" instead, like so:

```
$img = new Imagick("shape.png");
$clut = new Imagick();
$clut->newImage(1, 1, new ImagickPixel('#99ccff'));
$img->clutImage($clut);
$clut->destroy();
```

Hope it helps anyone else having this issue.

Comment: Two things: 1) this should be marked as the correct answer as it entirely avoids the "darkening issue" the original question referenced... which I also experienced and how I ended up here. 2) I'm 100% certain the $image you use above was supposed to be $img.  Great great answer.  Thank you MrE.

Comment: @ArtGeigel agreed I edited the typo. It should be img.

Answer (score 2):

```
 $img = new Imagick("shape.png");
 $img->colorizeImage("#99ccff",0.0);
```

That second parameter is opacity. If you set it to 1.0, it will match #99ccff 100%. You can set it to 0.5 to meet 50% over the original layer, etc:

```
 $img = new Imagick("shape.png");
 $img->colorizeImage("#99ccff", 1.0);
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This still gives me a darker color. I had to change the 1.0 to 1 to get it work, otherwise its transparent.

Comment: Confirmed on my end too... had to just make it "1" and not "1.0" for it to behave as intended.

Answer (score 1):

You must provide opacity, and opacity value MUST be integer 1,

```
$img->colorizeImage('#99ccff', 1);
```

or it does not work, i have tested a bit and i think to work with transparency you need to provide alpha channel.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. This still gives me a darker color, do you have any example to change the alpha?